# listview in html-select

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

I wrote this code:

```
<select id="selectCategories" runat="server">
    <option value="-1">Categories</option>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvCategories" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <option value="<%# Eval("ID") %>"><%# Eval("NAME") %></option>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</select>
```

and the browser gave me:
'HtmlSelect' cannot have children of type 'ListView'.

I dont want to insert the select into the listview or remove the runat from the select.
What can I do?

Comment: I don't think this code does what you think it does.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  Just adding categories to your select dynamically?

Comment: yeah, thats what i'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score -1):

a select element can only contain option or optgroup elements

try the optGroup element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/optgroup

also, the following video will teach you how to do what you are trying to

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-the-ability-to-create-groups-with-the-listview-control-for-different-data